# conditionally define reference variables in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to conditionally initialize a reference variable in a similar way to this program, but it is not possible to do it in the following manner :

```
#include <vector>

void test(bool val){

  std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0));
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > &ref_mat; // This is not allowed

  if(val){
    ref_mat = mat;
  }else{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat2 = Somefunction(); // The returned 2D vector from some function
    ref_mat = mat2;
  }

}
```

Can be this done in a different way? I need to only create a new object `mat2` if necessary, so I can save memory.

Comment: Using a reference to `mat2` would lead to undefined behavior. `mat2` is destroyed once you leave the `else` block.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The problem is I need to only create a new object mat2 if necessary, so I can save memory.

Comment: Do you need the `mat` at all when you create the `mat2`?

Comment: Isn't this the reason why god invented pointers? Or am I missing something? Why would you use references?

Comment: @Cauchy in any case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42285234/7359094) by Kerrek SB eliminates the need for a reference and any problem related to vector lifetime.

Comment: @Kupto if god invented anything then for sure not pointers

Comment: @tobi303: As we say on Arrakis, god invented pointers to test the faithful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about an even better way to structure that code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat =
     val ? std::vector<std::vector<int>>(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0))
         : SomeFunction();
```

No references needed at all!

---

If you *always* need the default vector around, and only conditionally need the other vector, then you can do something a bit longer like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat_dflt(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0));
std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat_cond;  // small when empty!

auto & mat = val ? mat_dflt : (mat_cond = SomeFunction());
```

(Note that an empty vector occupies only a very small amount of space on the stack.)

Comment: In the OP's example `mat` the `vector(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0))` is created and accessible in either case. You can just name it and move it to top to recreate that. But it's unclear whether it's intended or an artifact of the attempt to provide an example.

Comment: My problem is I need to only create a new object mat2 if necessary while always keeping `mat` object in memory, so I can save memory. Your approach overwrites `mat` with `mat2`.

Comment: @Cauchy: Does the reference need to be mutable?

Answer (score 2):

I like to divide my functions to as many small functions as I can.

Here's another option.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > getDefaultArray()
{
   return std::vector<std::vector<int> >(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0));
}

std::vector<std::vector<int> > getArray(bool val)
{
   return val ? getDefaultArray() : Somefunction();
}

void test(bool val)
{
   std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat = getArray(val);
   // Use mat
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a reference, you can workaround this issue by first using a pointer:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > mat(10, std::vector<int>(10, 0));
std::vector<std::vector<int> > *p_mat;

if(val)
    p_mat = &mat;
else
    p_mat = &SomeFunction();

std::vector<std::vector<int> > &ref_mat = *p_mat;
```

Comment: It's not clear whether `SomeFunction` returns a glvalue, and it's likely that it doesn't, in which case you can't take the address of the return value.